# Produce result faster than "Table[If[...]]"

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation, filtering, conditional

I would like to generate a list of output satisfying some condition for instance an equation but faster than the following code:

```
t=4;p=20;
Union[Flatten[Table[If[t<=(4a b d-1)c/(a+b)<=t+1,{(4a b d-1)c/(a+b)},0],{a,1,p}, {b,1,a},{d,1,p},{c,1,p(a+b)/(4a b d-1)}],4]]
```

which gives

```
{0, 9/2, 23/5, 14/3, 5}
```

Also I do not need $0$ in the output.

Thanks.

Comment: `AbsoluteTiming` of your function gave me `0.016115`.  Do you need faster than that or is your real problem larger?

Comment: @ChrisK, of course it was an example. but if you give larger $p,t$, then time consuming will increase much.

Comment: To get rid of the zero, just replace it in the if clause with `Nothing`. For marginally better speed, you could use Reap, Sow.

Comment: @asad how big do you need to go? My sense is that it could be an issue of memory if the parameter space is too large. You could pretty trivially feed this into `Compile` though and that might give you a decent speed up. In version 12 you can also use `FunctionCompile` and provide better type hinting which might be useful if you can use a type with a smaller memory footprint.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has an analytical solution for given t and p

```
sol = Reduce[t <= (4 a b d - 1) c/(a + b) <= t + 1 && 1 <= a <= p && 1 <= b <= a && 1 <= d <= p && 1 <= c <= p (a + b)/(4 a b d - 1), {a, b, c, d}, Integers]
```

and `Reduce` seems to scale better with increasing p. Actually above p=200  it looks like it takes always around 14 sec on my machine